# Add DirectX reference in Visual c# 2010 using windows 8

Tags: c#, directx-11

I'm new to c#. How can i add DirectX in Visual C# 2010 project? I'm using windows 8. I can't find a way to install directX in windows 8. When i try to add reference i'm not able to find directX in c:/windows/Microsoft.NET. What's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft no longer provides a .NET binding to DirectX; [Managed DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_DirectX) has been deprecated for over a decade, and XNA Game Studio seems to have been abandoned. Use [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/).

Comment: So its not possible to use directX without using any library?